# Transparent and not blur effect on keyboard on an iPad 3 both iOS 7 and 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, keyboard, transparency

My application have to work and all iPad from iPad 3 to iPad Air 2. I have a UITextField with the value "keyboardAppearance" set to **UIKeyboardAppearanceDark**. It works fine except on an iPad 3. On iPad 3, the keyboard has transparency but no blur effect but on others iPads, the keyboard has transparency with blur effect (this is what I want on all iPads).

Any guess why ?

PS : I'm not allowed to post a screenshot so if you need more details, feel free to ask.

Comment: It´s important to know the iOS versions of your devices. B.e UIKeyboardAppearanceDark is available in iOS 7.0 and later.

Comment: I've got the problem on iOS 7 and 8 but like I said only on iPad 3.